# Detect if background fetch is running

Tags: flutter, background-fetch

I am using `background_fetch`, How can I check If this package's service is running or not?

Currently I can start or stop the service and they have a return type which can indicate their status (Successful or Not), But after running how can I know If the service is still running programmatically?

A function which can give me about the status of service, Whether It's running or stopped.

Comment: You can just print the status everytime you want to check if its still running or not. Did you mean you want to have something like a listener to see the status in live time?

Comment: No, live time update is not required, How can I get the status of running background fetch service with background_fetch?

Comment: The same way you start and stop, `var status = await BackgroundFetch.status`

Comment: But It's always 2 which means It's available but doesn't mean that the BG service is live.

Comment: Maybe you can check this https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/issues/293